# Why NativeModules are not working in the Android App. Working fine in iOS

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, bridge

I have tried all the solutions available, but can't understand why NativeModules are not working in the Android App. The same code working perfectly in iOS

Here is how my native modules in Android look like

```
final class HelloModule extends ReactContextBaseJavaModule {

    HelloModule(ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
        super(reactContext);
    }

    /**
     * @return the name of this module. This will be the name used to {@code require()} this module
     * from JavaScript.
     */
    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return "HelloNativeModule";
    }

    @ReactMethod
    public void openViewDummy() {
        Log.d("hello", "openViewDummy called");
    }

}
```

HelloModule.java

```
* Exposes {@link HelloPackage} and {@link HelloPackage}  to JavaScript.
 * One {@link ReactPackage} can expose any number of {@link NativeModule}s.
 */
final class HelloPackage implements ReactPackage {

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public List<NativeModule> createNativeModules(@NonNull ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
        List<NativeModule> modules = new ArrayList<>();
        modules.add(new HelloModule(reactContext));
        return modules;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public List<ViewManager> createViewManagers(@NonNull ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
        return Collections.emptyList();
    }
}
```

HelloPackage.java

```
public final class MainApplication extends Application implements ReactApplication {

    private static final String JS_BUNDLE_NAME = "index.bundle";
    private static final String JS_MAIN_MODULE_NAME = "index";

    private final ReactNativeHost mReactNativeHost = new ReactNativeHost(this) {
        @Override
        public boolean getUseDeveloperSupport() {
            return BuildConfig.USE_DEVELOPER_SUPPORT;
        }

        /**
         * Returns the name of the main module. Determines the URL used to fetch the JS bundle
         * from the packager server. It is only used when dev support is enabled.
         */
        @NonNull
        @Override
        protected String getJSMainModuleName() {
            return JS_MAIN_MODULE_NAME;
        }

        /**
         * Returns the name of the bundle in assets.
         */
        @NonNull
        @Override
        protected String getBundleAssetName() {
            return JS_BUNDLE_NAME;
        }

        @Override
        protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
            @SuppressWarnings("UnnecessaryLocalVariable")
            List<ReactPackage> packages = new PackageList(this).getPackages();
            packages.add(new Hello());
            return packages;
        }
    };

    /**
     * Get the {@link ReactNativeHost} for this app.
     */
    @Override
    @NonNull
    public ReactNativeHost getReactNativeHost() {
        return mReactNativeHost;
    }


    @Override
    @CallSuper
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        SoLoader.init(this, false);
    }
}
```

MainApplication.java

```
import { NativeModules } from 'react-native';

const { HelloModule } = NativeModules;

    // NativeModules.Hello.openViewDummy;
HelloModule.openViewDummy();
```

Trying to access this way from typescript.

I get NativeModule undefined error in Android, everything works fine in iOS.